# cannot use req (variable of type events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) as core.SwitchableAPIGatewayRequest value in argument to adapter.ProxyWithContext

Tags: go, aws-lambda, gorilla

I'm new to Golang. I can't seem to supply the argument needed to work with adapter.ProxyWithContext. According to this https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy@v0.13.0/gorillamux#GorillaMuxAdapter.ProxyWithContext it should accept API Gateway proxy event or API Gateway V2 event.

```
import (
    "context"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    routerProxy "github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy/gorillamux"
)

var adapter *routerProxy.GorillaMuxAdapter

func main() {
    cfg := config.NewConfig()
    s := app.NewApp(cfg, log)

    adapter = routerProxy.New(s.SetupRoutes())
    lambda.Start(lambdaHandler) // execute lambda and the specific lead handler
}

func lambdaHandler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    c, err := adapter.ProxyWithContext(ctx, req)
    return c, err
}


i'm having this error: 
``var req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest
cannot use req (variable of type events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) as core.SwitchableAPIGatewayRequest value in argument to adapter.ProxyWithContextcompilerIncompatibleAssign
```

Comment: Use one of the `NewXXX` functions from [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy@v0.13.0/core#SwitchableAPIGatewayRequest), the construct a new core request from the given event request. The pass that core request to adapter.ProxyWithContext. You may need to use `&` to get the address of the event request. And you may need to use `*` to dereference the pointer of the create core request.

Answer (score 2):

As commenter [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) noted, you can not directly pass the `events.APIGatewayProxyRequest` to `adapter.ProxyWithContext`.

You need to create a *new* instance of `SwitchableAPIGatewayRequest` and pass it to `ProxyWithContext`.

This should fix your issue:

```golang
import "github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-go-api-proxy/core"

[...]

func lambdaHandler(ctx context.Context, req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    return adapter.ProxyWithContext(ctx, *core.NewSwitchableAPIGatewayRequestV1(&req))
}
```